# How to use the return value of stored procedure in asp.net?

Tags: sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I use this stored procedure for get the number of records

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[Asbabbazi_A]
@count int output
AS
BEGIN
if(@count=0)
set @count =( select count(*)   from dbo.Table_asbabbazi where (active= 0))
end
```

now I want use the @count in  my project.I wrote  this codes for use the @count in method.

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        DataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("haftehbazardb");
        SqlCommandBuilder bldr = new SqlCommandBuilder(DataAdapter);

        SqlParameter returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("count", SqlDbType.Int);
        returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DataAdapter.Fill(ds, Table_asbabbazi);
        countrecords = (int)returnParameter.Value;
```

this codes have no error but when i use the (countrecords ) in my project the value of (countrecords )  is zero that is not right .
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the value as the output of the stored procedure, you will need to return it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[Asbabbazi_A]
@count int output
AS
BEGIN
if(@count=0)
set @count =( select count(*)   from dbo.Table_asbabbazi where (active= 0))

return @count
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing output parameters with a return value.

Return value is generally used to indicate the status of your procedure, it will be 0 if not specified, e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestProc @Out INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET @Out = 1 / 0;
        RETURN 0;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @Out = 0;
        RETURN 1;
    END CATCH
END
```

Then calling this with T-SQL;

```
DECLARE @out INT, @return INT;  
EXECUTE @Return = dbo.TestProc @out OUT;
SELECT [Return] = @return, [out] = @out;
```

Will give:

```
Return | out
-------+-----
   1   |  0
```

Since 0 is the default return value, this is why you are getting 0 out from `returnParameter`, you need to use `ParameterDirection.Output`:

```
SqlParameter returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("count", SqlDbType.Int);
returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Comment: show this error  :Procedure or function Asbabbazi_A has too many arguments specified.

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code that caused this error? It should literally be as simple as changing the parameter type from return to output